# How to replace the Comcast Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar

I have a Mac desktop computer and use Safari as my Browser on a Comcast account.  Comcast just sent a notice that they will shortly discontinue their Calendar application.   I have used this service for a long time and this is devastating to me as I depend on the calendar for notifications of important upcoming events.

Is there something comparable to the Comcast calendar service that will send me email reminders of upcoming events?

I am not the most computer literate person and will greatly appreciate any assistance in how to get this done.

Comment: Does Comcast customer support explain how to export your data or offer suggestions for easy transition to another service? Presumably you pay them monthly and they spent some amount of time thinking how this affects their paying customers.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any service *should* have email reminders.

Personally, I use [Outlook.com](https://outlook.live.com/owa/) and while I have no need for email reminders, I did confirm that the features is available.  See below

[image: Outlook.com Email Reminder]

You can use this with your existing email, but you will need to sign up with a new account. Your Mail App (email client) will be able to work with the Outlook.com service as well

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [Calendar](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/calendar/welcome) included in macOS and iCloud can do this.

It defaults to alerting with a notification but you can add alerts that send email